# Playwright: pass open context/page to globalTeardown

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

Here is my scenario:

testfile1 containing some tests
testfile2 containing some tests
...
testfileN containing some tests

1. I log into application in global-setup (using storageState as defined in docs - https://playwright.dev/docs/test-global-setup-teardown#example)
2. Executing testfile1...testfileN with this logged session
3. Now I would like to logout user from application after last executed test, however I have tests grouped into few test suites, so need some generic way to logout after last test, can't add logout method just after some specific test.

I tried to use globalTeardown, however I can't find a way to send open page to teardown and execute logout. Is it even possible or should I use some other method for this scenario?

Comment: Please share you minimal reproducible "code" example of the issue so that others can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue, so in case someone will have similar case:

- in global setup, I log user and save storage state in json file
- after executing all tests, global-teardown creates new browser context and use browserContext.addCookies() to insert cookies from saved storage
- then playwright can operate on given page, so it's possible to logout user via UI